# How can I connect MATLAB to mysql?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I need to connect MATLAB to mysql server database using Jdbc and display a table information in a matrix in MATLAB..

Comment: I use this free toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29615-adodb-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connction

```
 conn = database('dbname','username','password',...
                'Vendor','MySQL',...
                'Server','host');
```

displaying

```
sqlquery = 'select * from Vehicles';
curs = exec(conn,sqlquery);
curs = fetch(curs);
curs.Data
```

Hop it helps..